# Make a Firebase Database call every day once

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I got an iOS app and I'm storing values in Firebase per user. 
Every 24 hours I need to reset those values in Firebase automatically, even when the user does not open the app. 
Is it possible to do this in the app itself or do I need to write cloud code?

Comment: may i know what kind of data need to be updated ? . Because there is a way with cloud functions to update the values according to time but it depends on the data you want to modify.

Comment: I think without opening the app not possible. If app is not running (Foreground/background) you can't upload

Comment: @veereshkumbar is Right, If you want to update database without opening app, you have option for cloud function

Comment: I'm new to cloud code, could anyone direct me to the right direction writing a function that deletes a field in the database every 24 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can´t run this type of code when your application is not active. If you need to reset the data every 24 hours even when the user does not open the app it´s better to create a job in your backend to execute this type of action and separate this logic from the application.

An example of a job in your backend can be [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), since you´re already using Firebase.

> Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code
>   in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS
>   requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed
>   environment. There's no need to manage and scale your own servers.

Comment: we could do with **cloud functions**.

Comment: @Balasubramanian, yes you can with Cloud functions but OP asked if you can do this in the app, which you can´t and that was what I wrote. what I ment with "Create a job in your backend" was to use for example cloud functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way to do so. Firebase gives a cloud function support where you can write and read data whenever you want. just need to run the code ones with what type of data you want to update and then set a timer of 24 hours to change the existing data. Then you are ready to go.[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) is the link of Firebase Docs for cloud functions. Go through it for more deeper understanding

Answer (score 1):

> **Cloud Functions** for **Firebase** lets you automatically run `backend code` in response to events triggered by Firebase features
>   and HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in
>   a managed environment. There's no need to manage and scale your own
>   servers.

**Typical use cases might fall into these areas:**

- Notify users when something interesting happens.
- Perform Realtime Database sanitization and maintenance.
- Execute intensive tasks in the cloud instead of in your app.
- Integrate with third-party services and APIs.

Check this Use case: 
[What Can I Do with Cloud Functions: Use case](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases)